# Finding File Relative to Project Root in Python

Tags: python

My project folder is structured like so:

```
* project1/
    * data/
        * results.csv
    * documentation/
    * programs/
        * analysis.py
```

How would `analysis.py` be able to access `results.csv` relative to the `project1` folder (which is the root folder of the project)?

I know this is a question lots of people have asked and have had answered. It involves things like `__init__.py`, and setting up a `settings.py` file in the root where you declare `ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`. However, I cannot ever get these things to work, and I feel as if I'm missing something obvious.

Forgive me for being a Python noob who just cannot get this to work.

If somebody could walk through a very clear example of how they would get to this work, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a different answer if it were `results.py` and the question were "How do you import that from here," but "How do you load that" is pretty straightforward.

Remember that `__file__` is the relative path from your curdir to the python file it's being executed in. This lets us calculate the path in two ways: one using the modern `pathlib` stdlib library and one with `os` commands.

```py
# using pathlib
from pathlib import Path

thisfile = Path(__file__)
programs = thisfile.parent
project1 = programs.parent
data = project1 / 'data'  # yep, we're dividing by a string. pathlib is awesome
resultscsv = data / 'results.csv'

# or

resultscsv = Path(__file__).parent.parent / 'data' / 'results.csv'
```

```py
# using os
import os.path

thisfile = os.path.abspath(__file__)
programs = os.path.dirname(thisfile)
project1 = os.path.dirname(programs)
data = os.path.join(project1, 'data')
resultscsv = os.path.join(data, 'results.csv')

# or

resultscsv = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'data', 'results.csv')

# or POSSIBLY, but this might not work in all places

resultscsv = os.path.join(__file__, '..', '..', 'data', 'results.csv')
```

The pathlib approach looks massively more readable to me, and is compounded with the fact that then *opening* the file becomes:

```
with resultscsv.open(mode='r') as f:
    ...
```

rather than the (slightly) more obtuse

```
with open(resultscsv, mode='r') as f:
    ...
```

Comment: Note that while this answer stays well away from the observation that your folder structure is probably just wrong, that does not make it any less true. `analysis.py` should probably never need to know where `results.csv` is. The question "How should I structure this project" is, however, both A) substantively different and B) probably off-topic for SO as "opinion based."

Comment: I'm interested in hearing your opinion! Why do you think my folder structure is wrong?

Comment: Mostly because of how you should logically group your project. `programs.analysis` should not be consulting `data.results` directly -- that's coupling those two remote areas of your code too tightly. If I were writing this I would have code directly under `project1` call into some code in the `data` package to read results.csv and return it, then hand that data directly off to `programs.analysis`.

Comment: Consider if you stop using csv files to provision your application with data, and start streaming from JSON instead (or any other data deserialization technique). How much code would have to change in your case (everything in analysis.py that knows how to get CSV files, _where_ to get them, how to understand them, etc), versus my case (just the module in `data` that's in charge of deserialization)

Comment: I may be breaking stackoverflow rules, but how would you go about importing the module in data in charge of serialization? i.e. the alternate question you proposed, "This would be a different answer if it were results.py and the question were 'How do you import that from here?'"

Comment: I would also note this isn't an application perse, but it is a data science project. I'm fairly certain the `results` file will always be a .csv file. Nevertheless, I'm always interested to hear from people in the engineering world! There is much I can learn from you all when it comes to making better pipelines.

Comment: @drizzle123 sure. I'd put `project1` in your [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) so you can import it, add `__init__.py`s to all your directories to turn them into packages, determine where you want your entrypoint to be (which mostly has to do with how your code is called from the outside world) and `import project1.data` (which is your `__init__.py` in the `data` directory). Write a loader function in there that returns the data, then `import project1.programs.analysis` and call the consumer from there.

Comment: There's no concern about code in `project1.programs.analysis` using _data_ from `project1.data`, only about it learning how to go and access that data. Some other code should serve as vehicle for that.

Comment: Would you be able to: 1) post what the modified structure would like with adding the __init__.py's 2) how one would go about adding project1 to the sys.path permanently so to speak? How would one go about making it "portable" so others could still use it? 3) I'm a little confused as to why your splitting up the code... I think I understand that it keeps the code more modular so to speak, but I think I'm a bit fuzzy on how exactly the code is being partitioned between different files. But I ask a lot, and I appreciate all you've done so far w/ no expectation of further help :)

Comment: @drizzle123 I'll only address #2 since the rest is either already spelled out (1) or out of scope (2). the PYTHONPATH environment variable is automatically added to `sys.path` to that's where I'd start. To make it portable, I'd look into packaging it with `setuptools` and providing an entrypoint. [`click`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) is a good third-party package for making a CLI that I'd probably turn this program into, if this is the extent of it.